# How to solve the inverse problem of least-squares?

Tags: linear-algebra

Focusing on following least squares problem:
  $$\min\limits_{V} \lVert Z - WV \rVert _{_F}^2$$

$$Z∈{R}^{m*n},\quad W∈{R}^{m*k},\quad V∈{R}^{k*n},\quad k\lt m\lt n $$
  This problem can be easily solved given $Z$ and $W$. I assume the solution of this problem as $\overline{V}$.

My question is that,  how can we recover $W$ by $\overline{V}$ and $Z$?

I found something called Inverse Optimization, but cannot figure out the relationship between them.